# XMLEditor Control for a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, asp.net-4.0

In a web application we have got some XML tags (not a complete xml file) to manipulate. At the moment there is a TextBox control and I want a proper editable control there, with indentation. Is there any good ready-made control that provides such functionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

http://xmlwebpad.codeplex.com/